# Oracle sql query to get records group by few columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to fetch records from a few tables in Oracle.
Query i have returns records as below.

[image: Oracle query and table]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Are you sure the first query works in Oracle? You don't have a `GROUP BY` clause but some columns are aggregated...

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear on my question. But Tejash answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the group by and case when directly in your query as following:

```
select 
  sum(case when t3.id = 1 then 1 end) as type1,
  sum(case when t3.id = 2 then 1 end) as type2,
  sum(case when t3.id = 3 then 1 end) as type3,
  t2.name
from t0 ra
Join table1 t1 on t1.id = ra.id
Join table2 t2 on t2.id = ra.id
join table3 t3 on t3.id = ra.typeid
where t1.column1 = 1
Group by t2.name;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current query works (it doesn't seem to be valid in Oracle) you could use it as a CTE and get the result you want. For example:

```
with
x (appcount, typeid, name) as (
  -- your current query here...
)
select 
  sum(case when typeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as type1,
  sum(case when typeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as type2,
  sum(case when typeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as type3,
  name
from x
group by name
```